# Export wp-content via WordPress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Anyone know if there's a way to export the wp-content directory from the WP dashboard? I've inherited a project where the previous developer is not being cooperative. I would like to circumvent his uncooperativeness and just export the theme, uploads, plugins, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can  use the [backupwordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/backupwordpress/)  plugin to get back up of all the wordpress and database  and  for the editing  you can try file manager  and other related plugin

Comment: Nice! I always assumed those backup plugins were for DB only. This worked perfect.

Comment: This plugin is just for DB though. I just tried it and it only backs up the DB in an SQL-file

Comment: You can use duplicator for same now  for migration and back full with files and database @Bossan

Answer (score 0):

The [File Manager plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-file-manager/) was what did it for me. Install it, click the new icon in the sidebar to go to the plugins file-browser, and right click to download the folder or file you want.